# Export existing namespace as another module

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a module that declares a namespace with some properties. For example:

```
declare module "database" {
  export namespace Database {
    namespace statics {
      type static1 = any;
      type static2 = any;
    }
  }
  const database: Database;
  export default database;
}
```

I can use `import { Database } from "database"` and then use `Database.statics.static` as a type.

I want to create another module that will allow you to import the statics directly. For example: `declare module "database/statics"`

I want to avoid rewriting all of the type definitions as there may be a lot more than in my example.  I have tried moving the module definitions out, but then I'm not sure how to do something like:

```
declare namespace Database { ... }
declare module "database/statics" {
  export = Database.statics;
}
```

The above gives me `Property 'statics' does not exist on type 'Database'`.

I guess the sum of my question is essentially: is there any way to export a namespace from a module that is declared in another module?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is to use a [triple slash reference directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) to tell typescript to import definitions from another file/module:

database.d.ts:

```
declare module "database" {
    export namespace Database {
        namespace Statics {
            export type static1 = any;
            export type static2 = any;
        }
    }
}
```

database-static.d.ts:

```
///<reference path="database.d.ts"/>

declare module "database-statics" {
    import {Database} from "database";
    import Statics = Database.Statics;

    export = Statics;
}
```

The above example works with those two `.d.ts` files in the same directory.  If you split those out into separate modules, you would use a `///<reference types="database"/>` instead.

One thing to note is that this will make the two modules dependent on each other, so you really aren't accomplishing much by exporting the definitions from a second module.

```
import * as Statics from "database-statics";
```

Would be no different from

```
import {Database} from "database";
import Statics = Database.Statics;
```

and the two modules containing your two `.d.ts` files would both need to be present in the first case